# Joining values from a single column based on customer number

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2019

Currently I am working to join delivery frequencies without having the items repeated since there are two different delivery frequencies for some customers. The code below the image is what I am trying to work out, but it takes every entry of the Frequency column for every customer and combines them.

[image: What I am getting]

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CUSNO,ITEM,Description,InvoiceDate,QShp,LAST_NAME,ItemType,RouteFreq,
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(FREQ AS VARCHAR(MAX))
 FROM Secondary AS S1 WHERE (FREQ = S1.FREQ)FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE 
).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS FREQ
FROM Secondary
GROUP BY CUSNO,ITEM,Description,InvoiceDate,QShp,LAST_NAME,ItemType,RouteFreq,FREQ
```

What I am trying to make is a column that will only show the two different frequencies into one row per customer number.

[image: What I want]

Comment: Why are you using the old `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) method when you're on 2019?

Comment: Though, *because* you are using the "old" method, why can't you just dump a `DISTINCT` in there?

Comment: Please post the original data table in a text-format. Combining DISTINCT and GROUP BY is 100% a sign of things going very wrong already though

Answer (score 0):

You code is using different columns, so I may be overlooking something.

**Data**

```
if(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_Secondary') is not null)
    drop table #tmp_Secondary

CREATE TABLE #tmp_Secondary(customer int, item nvarchar(50), date datetime, Qty int, [Type] nvarchar(50), Frequency nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO #tmp_Secondary
VALUES 
    (100100, 'item 1', '2023-12-15', 102, 'HardGood', 'W4'),
    (100100, 'item 1', '2023-12-15', 102, 'HardGood', 'Y1'),
    (100100, 'Rental item 1', '2023-12-15', 0, 'Rental', 'W4'),
    (100100, 'Rental item 1', '2023-12-15', 0, 'Rental', 'Y1')
```

**Stuff** This just needed to link to the outer query on the customer and the item. After that it works as expected.

```
SELECT customer,item,date,Qty,type,
    STUFF(
        (SELECT 
            ', ' + CAST(Frequency AS VARCHAR(MAX))
         FROM #tmp_Secondary AS S1 
         WHERE (ts.customer = S1.customer AND ts.item = s1.item)
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,''
    ) AS FREQ
FROM #tmp_Secondary ts
GROUP BY customer,item,date,Qty,type
```

**STRING_AGG** Because the query is grouped on customer,item,date,Qty,type the frequency will aggregate to the same grouped row. You do not need to add the WITHIN GROUP, but it allows you to add a sort if needed.

```
SELECT customer, item, date, Qty, type,
    STRING_AGG(Frequency, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY Frequency ASC) AS Combined
FROM #tmp_Secondary
group by customer, item, date, Qty, type
```

**Results**

| customer | item | date | Qty | type | Combined |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100100 | item 1 | 2023-12-15 00:00:00.000 | 102 | HardGood | W4,Y1 |
| 100100 | Rental item 1 | 2023-12-15 00:00:00.000 | 0 | Rental | W4,Y1 |